# Milk utensil found in meat cabinet

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk, shulchan-aruch

Say one has 2 cabinets, one for meat, one for milk, and found, for example, a milk knife in the meat cabinet and are uncertain as to how it got there. Say they are uncertain as to if it was washed in the wrong sink and put in meat cabinet or washed in the correct sink, milk sink, and put in the meat cabinet. What should be done? Please provide sources if possible!

Comment: The OP *was* asking for sources so I edited to depersonalize.

Comment: Since it would anyway be presumed to have been unused in over 24 hrs, the rule is probably to be lenient. (and welcome to Mi Yodeya!)

Comment: https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/chapter-95/

Comment: 11. One found a dairy vessel amongst the meat vessels or vice versa:
Found in drying rack, cabinet, or drawer:[263] If one found a dairy vessel on his meat drying rack or inside the meat drawer, the vessels remain permitted.[264] [This applies even if one is accustomed to wash his dishes in hot Keli Rishon water.[265] Some Poskim[266] rule that this applies even if one knows for certain that both vessels were Ben Yomo or dirty with meat and milk, nevertheless, everything remains permitted.[267]

Comment: Other Poskim[268], however, rule that if one knows for certain that the vessels were dirty with food, or Ben Yomo, and he is accustomed to wash the vessels in a Keli Rishon, then it is forbidden unless the water contained 60x versus the residue.[269] Practically, one is to Kosher all the Kosherable vessels, and those vessels which are not Kosherable may be used after 24 hours.[270] If one is not accustomed to wash the vessels in hot Keli Rishon water, it is Kosher in all cases, even if one knows that the vessels were dirty and Ben Yomo.]

Comment: "And if one finds a dairy plate among meat plates we are not concerned that they may have been washed together in a way that renders them prohibited." Rama YD 95:3  Not to mention that nowadays, dishes are generally washed with soap, which should mean there's no concern of a pleasant (or any?) taste added.